# Response from using a brand new Google API Server Key says 'The provided API key is expired'

Tags: php, api, google-maps

I have recently created a Google developer account, attached credit card info for billing, enabled the Places API, and created a server key and attached my server ip address - but when I attempt to access the API in my code, I get a response of:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => REQUEST_DENIED
    [error_message] => The provided API key is expired.
)
```

The endpoint I am using for API access is: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=$query&type=$type&sensor=true&key=$serverkey

Is that error_message possibly a symptom of another problem? Perhaps I'm using the wrong endpoint, or the wrong type of API key? It seems odd that a brand new server key would be expired...

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client This API client may help avoid problems with passing credentials properly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need a browser key, as opposed to a server key.